# Postgresql 8.2 Data dump to Postgresql 10

Tags: arrays, binary-data, data-migration, postgresql-10, postgresql-8.2

I have two servers

1. Windows Xp (running Postgresql 8.2)
2. Ubuntu TLS 18.o (running Postgresql 10)

I have a table which contains blob data of images and fingerprints in PostgreSQL 8.2. Application was built on VB6.

I migrated the database dump to PostgreSQL 10 but when the application is at the login screen it verifies from BlOB returned from the database, but the migrated data returned BLOB is not verifying with captured blob from the thumb machine digital persona. But if application is run with PostgreSQL 8.2 it connects but with migrated data to PostgreSQL 10 it doesn't.

Can anyone tell me what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Do you mean `bytea` with "blob data", or "large objects? If it's `bytea` it's probably cause by the change in [bytea_escaping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT) that happened several releases ago

Comment: yes blob data i am talking about . can you please guide me if this can be solved ...